# How to map array in react js which contains object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

index.js

```
const UserSearch = ({ user }) => {

    const [resultsToShow, setResultsToShow] = useState([])

    const maxDistance = useFilter('matchaMaxDistance', 100, 'number')
    const minAge = useFilter('matchaMinAge', 20, 'number')
    const maxAge = useFilter('matchaMaxAge', 120, 'number')
    const minFame = useFilter('matchaMinFame', 100, 'number')
    const requiredTag = useFilter('matchaRequiredTag', '', 'text')

    const sortFormProps = ({ user, resultsToShow, setResultsToShow })
    const filterFormProps = ({ user, requiredTag, maxDistance, minFame, minAge, maxAge })

    const requiredTagFound = tags => tags && requiredTag.value
        ? tags.split('#').includes(requiredTag.value)
        : true

    const filterResults = () => resultsToShow
        ? resultsToShow
            .filter(r => r.distance <= maxDistance.value &&
                r.age.years >= minAge.value && r.age.years <= maxAge.value
                && r.fame >= minFame.value && requiredTagFound(r.tags))
        : []
var unblockedUser = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        var coords = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedMatchaUser'));
        var from_user_id = coords.user_id;
        
        var res = filterResults();
        console.log(typeof res)
        res.map((r) => {
            var to_user_id = r.user_id;
            blockService.blockedUser({from_user_id, to_user_id})
            .then(res => {
                //If this row exist in the table it return 1 otherwise 0
                if (res.value === 0)
                {
                    //console.log(r);
                    unblockedUser.push(r)
                }
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(("Error: couldn't get block info"))
            })
        })
    }, [filterFormProps])
    //console.log(unblockedUser)

    return <>

        <ListOfUsers users={unblockedUser} />

    </>
}

export default UserSearch
```

ListOfUsers.js

```
const ListOfUsers = ({ users }) => {
    console.log(users);

    return  (
        users && users.length > 0
            ? <ListGroup className="text-left" variant="flush">
                {users.map(u => <Link to={`/users/${u.user_id}`} key={u.user_id}>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <div style={{display: "inline-block", width: "60%"}}>{u.username}, {u.age.years}</div>
                            <div style={{display: "inline-block", width: "40%", textAlign: "right"}}>{parseInt(u.distance)} km<br />
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAward} /> {u.fame}</div>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                </Link>)}
            </ListGroup>
            : <div className="text-info">Could not find any matching users<br />please try different filters</div>
    )
}
```

I am working with users search. My ultimate goal is to display list of users except blocked users as a search result of logged user. What I am trying to do here is that I am sending **unblockedUser** as a props to ***ListOfUsers*** component. In ***ListOfUsers*** component, if I console user props it looks like following image
[image]

My question is that why my map function is not working here in ***ListOfUsers*** component. How can I make it working? Also if I console the length of users it returns undefined.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you define `unblockedUser` outside of your `useEffect` hook, then update `unblockedUser` asynchronously within that `useEffect`. So `unblockedUser` doesn't get its content until after the render is complete (when it's too late) and on the next render `unblockedUser` is redefined to be an empty list.

To fix this, I would store `unblockedUser` as a state variable, then you can update it however you like and changes will be rendered accordingly.

For example (with minimal changes to your existing code):

```js
const [unblockedUser, setUnblockedUser] = React.useState([]); // changed

useEffect(() => {
    var coords = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedMatchaUser'));
    var from_user_id = coords.user_id;
    
    var res = filterResults();
    console.log(typeof res)
    setUnblockedUser([]); // clear before rerunning
    res.map((r) => {
        var to_user_id = r.user_id;
        blockService.blockedUser({from_user_id, to_user_id})
        .then(res => {
            //If this row exist in the table it return 1 otherwise 0
            if (res.value === 0)
            {
                //console.log(r);
                setUnblockedUser(prev => [...prev, r]); // changed
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(("Error: couldn't get block info"))
        })
    })
}, [filterFormProps])
//console.log(unblockedUser)

return <ListOfUsers users={unblockedUser} />
```

In the example above, I've made as few changes to your code as possible to make the change easier to follow. You may find that more modifications would improve this code. For example, you might want to check all the user records first, get a single array of unblocked users, then call `setUnblockedUser` once instead of several times. But up to you.

Comment: Hello @Henry, thanks for the comment. Your code produce this warning **Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `10`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may**

This code renders the component for infinity times (it doesn't stop). This means that it continuously hit the database and retrieve the data from table. It doesn't stop. I had to stop the backend server which is node js. Do know why this happens?

Comment: I have updated my question with other parts of my code. Please check :)

Comment: @MahmudulHasan Oh yeah was missing a call to clear `unblockedUser` before repopulating. Made an update

Answer (score 0):

I think is to create a getter, setter using unblockedUser as the `useState`.

```
const [unblockedUser, setUnblockedUser] = useState([]); // try it this

    useEffect(() => {
        const coords = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedMatchaUser'));
        const from_user_id = coords.user_id;
        
        const res = filterResults(); //how does work filterResults() funtinon?
        console.log(typeof res)

        res.map((r) => {
            const to_user_id = r.user_id;
            blockService.blockedUser({from_user_id, to_user_id})
            .then(res => {
                //If this row exist in the table it return 1 otherwise 0
                if (res.value === 0)
                {
                    //console.log(r);
                    setUnblockedUser((prevState) => [...prevState, r]) //here
                }
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(("Error: couldn't get block info"))
            })
        })
    }, [filterFormProps]) // => [] to change
    //console.log(unblockedUser)

    return <>

        <ListOfUsers users={unblockedUser} />

    </>
```

You may not be fully functional because the function of the other function is not explained, but try it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. And here is the filterResults() function:

```
const filterResults = () => resultsToShow
  ? resultsToShow
   .filter(r => r.distance <= maxDistance.value &&
    r.age.years >= minAge.value && r.age.years <= maxAge.value
    && r.fame >= minFame.value && requiredTagFound(r.tags))
  : []
```

Comment: I have updated my question with other codes. Please check. Your above answer won't work. Your code renders the component for infinity times (it doesn't stop). This means that it continuously hit the database and retrieves the data from the table. It doesn't stop. I had to stop the backend server which is node js

Comment: @Mahmudul Hasan Please tell me `resultsToShow` what kind of value you want to renew. and 'filterResults'
The event updating `resultsToShow` to `setResultsToShow` is not in your code. 
The reason why renderings continue to occur is because we need to remove `[filterFormProps]` in `useEffect` and see if it works. `[filterFormProps]` => `[ ]`